# how to send SMS within my application windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i want to send sms within my application not show compose dialog any idea ?

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
    smsComposeTask.To = textBox1.Text;
    smsComposeTask.Body = textBox2.Text;
    smsComposeTask.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No way to directly send an SMS.

Comment: why ;( how do this... its important for me

Comment: because of privacy and security, you would not want any random app just sending texts from your phone without your knowledge, would you